# Guidelines to implement a minimal shape drawing tool desktop application using Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, swt, eclipse-gef

We need to implement a Java desktop application that allows us (initially) to create / edit / resize / polygons on (initially) images. Then these polygons would be mapped to objects in our domain model.

So we basically need a toolbar with the options describe above and the possibility for the example to create a polygon on the an image and then scale it, or resize it, just that.

Do you know some library that could facilitate our work?

We've analyzed [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/), [Picollo](http://www.piccolo2d.org/), [NetBeans Visual API](http://platform.netbeans.org/graph/), Plain Swing or SWT/JFace, but none of them seems to *help us* to achieve our goal, which is, implement a really basic image editing tool.

I would like to mention that I'm not saying that what I want to do is not possible with the analyzed libraries, of course it can be done, but I'd like to learn from your experiences which is the correct path to take for this problem.

Any suggestion will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use GEF and the eclipse plataform.

this [article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-GEF-diagram-editor/shape.html) could help you.

saluti

Comment: This seems a good start, maybe combining this information with this one: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-rcp1/section13.html a good solution can be created. Thanks.

Comment: If you need you cuold also try to generate the datamodel with EMF: there is an IBM redbook that could help you. http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246302.html

Answer (score 1):

You might look at [`GraphPanel`](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel), a simple object drawing program. The control components are arranged in a `JPanel`, but [`JToolBar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html) is a more flexible alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the links!, but I'm searching for a tool that facilitates the creation (and modification) of polygons.

Comment: I don't know of an existing library. If you adapt `GraphPanel`, add an `Edge` to connect the first and last `Node`. Your vertices don't need to be fancy, just big enough to select. I'd consider `java.awt.Polygon` for the vertex container.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help, I will add some comments here if we find a nice library that can help us with this. Picollo is nice, but we don't want to add all the complexity of picollo just for these needs. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at imagine.dev.java.net?  It is a NetBeans Platform application, which, though unfinished, might provide you with an interesting starting point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this link, we did not know the existence of this project, did you use it?